# SQL join that returns only records where all rows match

Tags: sql

I have a query with a join on three tables. one of the columns in the 3rd table has a boolean value. . table 2 and table 3 are connected with product_id, each product_id on table 3 can be associated with true and false value as received value. I need a query to return all records in table 1 where are associated with products which their received value in table 3 has only true value. 
In the sample data below I want to only return GHI

```
Table 1 - Sale
ID  sale#
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI

Table 2 PO      Table 1 join Table 2 on Table1.ID = Table 2.SaleID
ID SaleID
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   3

Table 3
ID POID  Received Table 2 right join table 3 on Table 2.ID = Table 3.POID 
1   1     True
2   1     False
3   2     True
4   3     False
5   4     True
6   5     True
7   5     True
```

After the afternoon experimenting I make it work using a NOT IN, but it is very slow with my data set (which is only about 2000 records currently)  I think it is probably because it is having to recreate the joins.  It seems like there should be  a more elegant way to accomplish this.

```
SELECT Distinct Table1.id, Table3.received
FROM Table3 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.saleID = Table1.id) 
  ON Table3.POID = Table2.id
WHERE ((Table3.received)=True) and Table1.id NOT IN (
  SELECT Table1.id
  FROM Table3 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.saleID = Table1.id) 
    ON Table3.POID = Table2.id
  WHERE ((Table3.received)=False));
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide some sample data and some of your code. i.e. screen shots, code snippets, current return, etc..

Comment: `I have a query with a 3 table join.` Please post the query you are working with.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StelioK, I included Sample Data that for some reason did not format correctly.  I edited it and seems better now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the query you need

```
select 
  Table1.* 
from 
  Table1 join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.saleid
  join table3 on table3.POID = Table2.ID
where
  table3.received = true
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns any values that have any received = true.  I need only values where ALL related table 3.received = true.

Answer (score 0):

first, only products have to be selected from table 3 that has true value entry in table3, this can be done by self join on POID. then the result can be joined with table2 and table1

```
select 
   Table1.* 
from 
Table1 join Table2 
   on Table1.id = Table2.saleid
join 
   (select t3.poid 
    from 
    Table3 t3 join Table3 t4
       on t.POID = Table4.POID) 
     where t3.received = true and t4.received  = true) all_true
on all_true.POID = Table2.ID
```

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong but Table 3 joined to table 3 returns any PO that has at least 1 true but can also have any number of False. I need only those where all are true

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make sure that the `count` of records for a particular `sale#` is equal to the `count` of records with a value of `received` = `True` a.k.a. a count-if (which doesn't explicitly exist in SQL). The way you accomplish a count-if in SQL is to do a `...sum(case ... when ... then 1 else 0 end)...`.

**Sample Data Setup:**

```
create table dbo.Sale
    (
        ID int
        , sale# char(3)
    )

create table dbo.PO
    (
        ID int
        , SaleID int
    )

create table dbo.Received
    (
        ID int
        , POID int
        , Received char(5)
    )

insert into dbo.Sale
values (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'DEF'), (3, 'GHI')

insert into dbo.PO
values (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,3)

insert into dbo.Received
values (1, 1, 'True')
    , (2, 1, 'False')
    , (3, 2, 'True')
    , (4, 3, 'False')
    , (5, 4, 'True')
    , (6, 5, 'True')
    , (7, 5, 'True')
```

**Answer:**

```
; with base as
    (
        select s.sale#
        , p.SaleID
        , r.POID
        , r.Received
        from dbo.Sale as s
        inner join dbo.PO as p on s.ID = p.SaleID
        inner join dbo.Received as r on p.ID = r.POID   
    )
    , all_true as
    (
        --this sub-query is the filter for Sale#'s of interest
        select b.sale#
        from base as b
        group by b.sale#
        having sum(case b.Received when 'True' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) --count-if = count 
    )
select b.*
from base as b
inner join all_true as t on b.sale# = t.sale#
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+--------+------+----------+
| sale# | SaleID | POID | Received |
+-------+--------+------+----------+
| GHI   |      3 |    4 | True     |
| GHI   |      3 |    5 | True     |
| GHI   |      3 |    5 | True     |
+-------+--------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks tarheel
you put me on the track.  I made the True/false a bit and added where Sum(received)= count(received)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.id
FROM Table3 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.saleID = Table1.id) ON Table3.POID = Table2.id
GROUP BY Table1.id
HAVING (-1*(Sum(Table3.received))=Count([Table3].[received]));
```